# Avoiding memory leaks using ArrayPool within a class

Tags: c#, arrays, garbage-collection

I have a class which I am currently using to build byte arrays (for network packets), it starts with some initial buffer, and resizes as more data is written to it. I want to reduce the amount of GC caused by this util by using an `ArrayPool`, but am having a hard time figuring out a good way to prevent memory leaks without too much overhead.

My main idea was to make my class `IDisposable` and return the array back to the pool in the `Dispose()` call.

```
using ByteBuilder builder = new ByteBuilder();
builder.AddData(); // Add a bunch of data
// write data to network stream
...
// builder is diposed and memory is returned to ArrayPool at the end of the method call
```

The problem here is that if it happens to be used without the using declaration, the memory would never be returned. Is there some way I can guarantee how someone uses it?

Another idea I had was to use a finalizer to return the memory to the array pool, but it seems that this has significant overhead from what I have read. I am allocating a lot of arrays, and many of them could be small, so having a finalizer seems like it may not be worth the trade off.

Comment: Finalizers in `C#` are not guaranteed to be called. Why do you want to _"reduce the amount of GC caused by this"_? Do you get some problems? GC is smart enough to deal with memory allocation by his own. If you would try to "help" him, you probably will just make things worse.

Comment: What makes you think you have a memory leak?  https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/

Comment: @vasily.sib creating loads of buffers repeatedly will put pressure on GC, that is what op is trying to avoid by using ArrayPool, renting and returning.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about forcing a developer to call Dispose. There are 100s of APIs out there that implement IDisposable that don't care if you call it or not, it is ultimately up to the developer to do the right thing. Just make sure that when your class does get disposed, that is disposes it correctly.

Comment: I do not agree with @JohanP, do worry about forcing a developer to call `Dispose`. This is why `IDisposable` contract was designed for (if there are misuses, should we follow bad patterns?). Java making finalizers deprecated and moving to explicit cleanup was a good choice, this is just better approach. Not using `using` may be checked statically at compile time.

Comment: @KonradKokosa if a class implements IDisposable, then absolutely a client should dispose it but tell me how that would work to force disposal? Even if a class implements IDisposable, what is to say you must dispose of it everytime ala HttpClient? Having your class be disposable and and using it correctly is different to forcing your clients to dispose it by having some nuget package that checks it at compile time.

Comment: We should not use a contrived example of `HttpClient`, which is just designed in a misleading way. For me I would like to perceive things simple - if something implements `IDisposable`, it must be disposed. Period.

Comment: @KonradKokosa We are all in agreement but the question is, how do you force other people that use your code to dispose it? `HttpClient` is certainly not a contrived example, it is a real world, legit issue that caused many problems. There are other cases too, where you want some IOC container to dispose your class when it shuts down, like long running tcp connections and the user should NOT explicitly call dispose on that class.